# flex-pack at webkit

Tags: css, webkit, flexbox

On web exists information about CSS3 `box`, `flexbox` and `flex`. From what I understand, the `flex` is the current *draft* method, for now. So on webkit we use `display: -webkit-flex`, `-webkit-flex: 1 auto`...

But my question is: how I can use something like `box-pack: start` on `flex`?

Take a look in [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fzsav/) (webkit only). I need pack it to top, but it is spreading. It'll be similar to [**this hackish example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cKStN/) (but not is good for my case, hard to maintance). How I can fix that?

## NEED TO FIX

**HTML**

```
<div class="body">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div class="box" style="width: 80%"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 20%"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 20%"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 20%"></div>
    <!-- (NEED TO FIX) EMPTY SPACE -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    -webkit-flex: 1 100%;
}

.body {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 400px;
}
```

So note that `h1` need use all space from *line 1*, 2nd and 3rd `.box` will go to *line 2*, 4th and 5th `.box` on *line 3* and *I need* that the `.body` (that is bigger than content, in *height*) have a empty space on bottom.

## HACKISH SOLUTION :-(

**HTML**

```
<div class="body">
    <h1 style="height: 40px;">Test</h1>
    <div class="box" style="width: 80%; height: 20px;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 20%; height: 20px;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 20%; height: 20px;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 20%; height: 20px;"></div>
    <div class="hackish"></div>
    <!-- NOTE THIS .hackish :-( -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hackish {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

So, some solution?

Answer (score 2):

*After write all and create examples to here, I found the solution, 5 seconds after. Grrr...*

I can simply use `-webkit-align-content: flex-start` on `.body` ([*W3 Flexbox - Align Content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#align-content)). So this is the solution:

```
.body {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 400px;

    -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
}
```

See [**this working**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fzsav/1/).